# How can i resolve internal server error with pgadmin4 and apache?

Tags: apache, pgadmin-4

I have installed pdadmin and when i want to run it i have

> 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

the log in apache give me this

> AttributeError: 'ReverseProxied' object has no attribute 'app'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this post](https://www.pg-forum.de/viewtopic.php?t=8105&p=39069), you can edit /usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py by adding a line "self.app = app". Here's my diff:

```
--- /usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py.20191205125322U.bak     2019-11-12 18:55:01.000000000 +0100
+++ /usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py 2019-12-05 14:01:01.337805713 +0100
@@ -70,6 +70,7 @@
 class ReverseProxied(object):
     def __init__(self, app):
         # https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/middleware/proxy_fix/#module-werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix
+        self.app = app
         try:
             from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
             self.app = ProxyFix(app,
```

This was a known bug, but as you can see, it is fixed in the meanwhile:

```
    frank@host ~/GIT/pgadmin4/web > git log c4facc04d3^..c4facc04d3
    commit c4facc04d3b64f3902131737970727a4c8c4d2d0
    Author: Aditya Toshniwal 
    Date:   Mon Dec 2 11:40:48 2019 +0530

        Fix pgAdmin4 failed to start issue after upgrading to version 4.15. Fixes #4978
```

```
    frank@host ~/GIT/pgadmin4/web > git diff c4facc04d3^..c4facc04d3
    diff --git a/docs/en_US/release_notes_4_16.rst b/docs/en_US/release_notes_4_16.rst
    index dc92d0c9c..74b4f7b9d 100644
    --- a/docs/en_US/release_notes_4_16.rst
    +++ b/docs/en_US/release_notes_4_16.rst
    @@ -38,3 +38,4 @@ Bug fixes
     | `Issue #4935 `_ -  Fix accessibility issues.
     | `Issue #4964 `_ -  Fix an issue where length and precision are not removed from table/column dialog.
     | `Issue #4965 `_ -  Fix an issue where the Interval data type is not displayed in the properties dialog of table/column.
    +| `Issue #4978 `_ -  Fix pgAdmin4 failed to start issue after upgrading to version 4.15.
    diff --git a/web/pgAdmin4.py b/web/pgAdmin4.py
    index 845ca52aa..4668458f0 100644
    --- a/web/pgAdmin4.py
    +++ b/web/pgAdmin4.py
    @@ -69,6 +69,7 @@ if not os.path.isfile(config.SQLITE_PATH):
     ##########################################################################
     class ReverseProxied(object):
         def __init__(self, app):
    +        self.app = app
             # https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/middleware/proxy_fix/#module-werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix
             try:
                 from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
```