# Internal Server Error when using pgadmin4.15 with apache on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, pgadmin-4

I pretty much followed [this post](http://%20https://tecadmin.net/install-pgadmin4-on-ubuntu/) to set up `pgadmin 4` on my `ubuntu 16.04`, I skipped the 1st step which installs `PostgreSql`, since I would like to use AWS RDS. But when I tried to launch `http://myipaddress/pgadmin4/`, I got `500 Internal Server Error`. `http://myipaddress` did get me to the **Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page**, not sure what configuration I am missing.

I also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59191528/how-can-i-resolve-internal-server-error-with-pgadmin4-and-apache/59293018#59293018) and added the suggested fix, but it doesn't work for me.

Here is the error in the `error.log`

```
[wsgi:warn] [pid 19605:tid 140528707069824] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.  
[wsgi:warn] [pid 19605:tid 140528707069824] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.  
[mpm_event:notice] [pid 19605:tid 140528707069824] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured -- resuming normal operations  
[core:notice] [pid 19605:tid 140528707069824] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'  
[wsgi:error] [pid 19608:tid 140528601200384] [remote 8.28.16.254:0] mod_wsgi (pid=19608): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.wsgi'.  
[wsgi:error] [pid 19608:tid 140528601200384] [remote 8.28.16.254:0] Traceback (most recent call last):  
[wsgi:error] [pid 19608:tid 140528601200384] [remote 8.28.16.254:0]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__  
[wsgi:error] [pid 19608:tid 140528601200384] [remote 8.28.16.254:0]     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)  
[wsgi:error] [pid 19608:tid 140528601200384] [remote 8.28.16.254:0]   File "/usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py", line 95, in __call__  
[pid 19608:tid 140528601200384] [remote 8.28.16.254:0]     return self.app(environ, start_response)  
[wsgi:error] [pid 19608:tid 140528601200384] [remote 8.28.16.254:0] AttributeError: 'ReverseProxied' object has no attribute 'app'
```

Comment: This question have been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59191528/how-can-i-resolve-internal-server-error-with-pgadmin4-and-apache)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem as you did and I tried to fix as per those links above as well, and this is what I did wrong: when I was editing /usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py I mistakenly put the plus symbol before self.app = app

```
 class ReverseProxied(object):
     def __init__(self, app):
         # https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/middleware/proxy_fix/#module-werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix
+        self.app = app
         try:
             from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
             self.app = ProxyFix(app
```

once I put

```
 class ReverseProxied(object):
     def __init__(self, app):
         # https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/middleware/proxy_fix/#module-werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix
         self.app = app
         try:
             from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
             self.app = ProxyFix(app
```

pgAdmin4 worked fine after system reboot. The + symbol is diff's command way to let user know about the differences between files being compared - that is what confused me. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the +symbol. For some reason, my indentation was messed up. Once I fixed it, it works fine.

```
  File "/usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py", line 83
    except ImportError:
                      ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```